# Granularity of difftime

Tags: c, c99, language-lawyer

In **section 7.23.2.2** paragraph 2 and 3 of the C99 standard:

> 2  The **`difftime`** function computes the difference between two calendar times: **`time1 -
>   time0`**.
>
> 3  The **`difftime`** function returns the difference expressed in seconds as a **`double`**.

The C99 standard does appear to define a *minimum granularity* for the `difftime` function only a *resolution* (seconds). Are there any implicit guarantees about the granularity of the `difftime` function?

I can reason that the *minimum possible granularity* on any given implementation depends on the granularity of the underlying representation of that implementation's `time_t` data type (since that is what is passed to `difftime`) -- but from my understanding of the text, `difftime` isn't required to return the difference at that *minimum* granularity, and could in fact return at a much *larger* one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no such guarantees made by the C standard. `time_t` has an arithmetic type, and is able to represent the implementation's best approximation of a calendar time (with implementation defined range and precision). `difftime` calculates the difference between two such `time_t` values, and returns the result in seconds. That's about all that the standard guarantees. Specifically, it does not say how granular/precise the value returned by `difftime` is (but it can be reasonably assumed to have the same granularity as the `time_t` type on the same implementation).

The POSIX standard gives one further guarantee, by specifying `time_t` to hold the seconds since the epoch (either as an integer or floating point type) - ie. it fixes the unit. Again, it does not say anything about the granularity though.

The main reason I can think of that neither of these standards specify the granularity, is that that is hardware dependent, and both standards specify the behavior of software (potentially running on a wide variety of hardware). They don't control the system clock, so can't make any assumptions about its granularity.

Comment: I think you've made a very important point about why granularity isn't specified: granularity is inherently dependent on hardware, and the C standard purposely avoids assumptions about hardware.